# Exploding text form lines into an array

Tags: php

I have a script that pulls in the Google Pagerank for inputted URLs.

I have tried editing the script so that instead of only being able to put 3 urls in you can paste a list of URL's in.

Unfortuantly when I past some URL's in it just puts them next to each other and doesn't display the Pagerank.

If you want to test it and see you can find it here: http://php-playground.co.cc/testdir/pagerank.php

(people have been reporting a virus on the URL but its only because its a co.cc domain, do not click if you are worried :)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//If the form was submitted
if(isset($_GET['url[]'])){
    //Put every new line as a new entry in the array
    $url = explode("\n",trim($_POST["url[]"]));
        }

        echo "$url";
?>
<?php
function fetch_google_page_rank($url) {
$url = strstr($url,"http://")? $url:"http://".$url;
$fp = fsockopen("toolbarqueries.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
    $out = "GET /tbr?client=navclient-    auto&ch=".CheckHash(HashURL($url))."&features=Rank&q=info:".$url."&num=100&filter=0   HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: toolbarqueries.google.com\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; GoogleToolbar 2.0.114-big; Windows XP   5.1)\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $data = fgets($fp, 128);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
    if($pos === false){} else{
            $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return (int)$pagerank;
}
}

function StrToNum($Str, $Check, $Magic) {
$Int32Unit = 4294967296; // 2^32
$length = strlen($Str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $Check *= $Magic;
    if ($Check >= $Int32Unit) {
        $Check = ($Check - $Int32Unit * (int) ($Check / $Int32Unit));
        $Check = ($Check < -2147483648)? ($Check + $Int32Unit) : $Check;
    }
    $Check += ord($Str{$i});
}
return $Check;
}

function HashURL($String) {
$Check1 = StrToNum($String, 0x1505, 0x21);
$Check2 = StrToNum($String, 0, 0x1003F);
$Check1 >>= 2;
$Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3F);
$Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FF);
$Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3C000 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FFF);
$T1 = (((($Check1 & 0x3C0) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C)) << 2 ) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F );
$T2 = (((($Check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($Check2 &    0xF0F0000 );
return ($T1 | $T2);
}

function CheckHash($Hashnum) {
$CheckByte = 0;
$Flag = 0;
$HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
$length = strlen($HashStr);
for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
    $Re = $HashStr{$i};
    if (1 === ($Flag % 2)) {
        $Re += $Re;
        $Re = (int)($Re / 10) + ($Re % 10);
    }
    $CheckByte += $Re;
    $Flag ++;
}
$CheckByte %= 10;
if (0!== $CheckByte) {
    $CheckByte = 10 - $CheckByte;
    if (1 === ($Flag % 2) ) {
        if (1 === ($CheckByte % 2)) {
            $CheckByte += 9;
        }
        $CheckByte >>= 1;
    }
}
return '7'.$CheckByte.$HashStr;
}
// Google PR Finder END



?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GET Google PR</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #333;
}
body {
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
pre{ font-size:15px;}
-->
</style></head>
<body>

<h2>Google PR</h2>
<p>Enter your URLs </p>
<form action="" method="POST">
<p>
<textarea name="url[]" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<!--<input name="url[]" type="text" id="url[]" value="http://" size="80" /><br />
<input name="url[]" type="text" id="url[]" value="http://" size="80" /><br />
<input name="url[]" type="text" id="url[]" value="http://" size="80" /><br />-->
</p>
<p><input name="findpr" type="submit" value="Find Google PageRank" />
<br />
<br />
</p>
</form>
<table>
<pre>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['findpr']))
{
foreach($_POST['url'] as $key => $url)
{
    if( $_POST['url'][$key]!="http://")
    echo "<td><b>PR:</td><td>" .  fetch_google_page_rank($_POST['url'][$key]) .     " </td><td></b>&raquo;</td><td>" . $_POST['url'][$key]."</td></tr><br />";
}
}
?>
</pre>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo "$url"; doesn't make sense. the output's gonna be always Array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
function fetch_google_page_rank($url) {
$url = strstr($url,"http://")? $url:"http://".$url;
$fp = fsockopen("toolbarqueries.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
    $out = "GET /tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=".CheckHash(HashURL($url))."&features=Rank&q=info:".$url."&num=100&filter=0   HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: toolbarqueries.google.com\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; GoogleToolbar 2.0.114-big; Windows XP   5.1)\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $data = fgets($fp, 128);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
    if($pos === false){} else{
            $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return (int)$pagerank;
}
}

function StrToNum($Str, $Check, $Magic) {
$Int32Unit = 4294967296; // 2^32
$length = strlen($Str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $Check *= $Magic;
    if ($Check >= $Int32Unit) {
        $Check = ($Check - $Int32Unit * (int) ($Check / $Int32Unit));
        $Check = ($Check < -2147483648)? ($Check + $Int32Unit) : $Check;
    }
    $Check += ord($Str{$i});
}
return $Check;
}

function HashURL($String) {
$Check1 = StrToNum($String, 0x1505, 0x21);
$Check2 = StrToNum($String, 0, 0x1003F);
$Check1 >>= 2;
$Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3F);
$Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FF);
$Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3C000 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FFF);
$T1 = (((($Check1 & 0x3C0) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C)) << 2 ) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F );
$T2 = (((($Check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($Check2 &    0xF0F0000 );
return ($T1 | $T2);
}

function CheckHash($Hashnum) {
$CheckByte = 0;
$Flag = 0;
$HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
$length = strlen($HashStr);
for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
    $Re = $HashStr{$i};
    if (1 === ($Flag % 2)) {
        $Re += $Re;
        $Re = (int)($Re / 10) + ($Re % 10);
    }
    $CheckByte += $Re;
    $Flag ++;
}
$CheckByte %= 10;
if (0!== $CheckByte) {
    $CheckByte = 10 - $CheckByte;
    if (1 === ($Flag % 2) ) {
        if (1 === ($CheckByte % 2)) {
            $CheckByte += 9;
        }
        $CheckByte >>= 1;
    }
}
return '7'.$CheckByte.$HashStr;
}
// Google PR Finder END



?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GET Google PR</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #333;
}
body {
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
pre{ font-size:15px;}
-->
</style></head>
<body>

<h2>Google PR</h2>
<p>Enter your URLs </p>
<form action="" method="POST">
<p>
<textarea name="url" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<!--<input name="url[]" type="text" id="url[]" value="http://" size="80" /><br />
<input name="url[]" type="text" id="url[]" value="http://" size="80" /><br />
<input name="url[]" type="text" id="url[]" value="http://" size="80" /><br />-->
</p>
<p><input name="findpr" type="submit" value="Find Google PageRank" />
<br />
<br />
</p>
</form>
<table>
<pre>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['findpr']))
{
$url = explode("\n",$_POST["url"]);
foreach($url as $key => $url_l)
{
$url_l=trim($url_l);
    if( $url_l!="http://")
    echo "<td><b>PR:</td><td>" .  fetch_google_page_rank($url_l) .     " </td><td></b>&raquo;</td><td>" . $url_l."</td></tr><br />";
}
}
?>
</pre>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok I have tested it and now I get this in the array 'code'Array ( [0] => www.google.com www.bing.com www.yahoo.co.uk )'code' I still cant figure out whats going on1

Comment: And the output of the code is this: '
PR: 0 » www.google.com www.bing.com www.yahoo.co.uk'

Comment: @adnan.shammount wow thank you! unfortunately there is still a slight error: **Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/play/public_html/testdir/pagerank.php on line 137** Which is this line **foreach($_POST['url'] as $key => $url)** :)

Comment: @RickyDawn, just made another update and tested it for you.. working without errors

Comment: @adnan.shammount You are a genius, but I don't mean to be a pain :) However the PR is not showing its just 0 all the time. I appreciate your help I've been stuck on this for the whole day!

Comment: @RickyDawn, I've just made some modifications, you can try it. It's now working but only for one url at a time.. I'll see what I can do for more

Comment: @adnan.shammount Cheers buddy! Annoying isn't it ;-)